# jquery disable radio group if MAX checked

Tags: jquery, html

How can I disable a group of radio buttons if MAX values are checked? In my example I want to allow a MAX of 2 radio buttons to be checked and when 2 are checked than disable the rest.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var MAX=2;              
    });
</script>

<form>
<div>
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rbutton"  name="radio[]" value="1" /></li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rbutton"  name="radio[]" value="2" /></li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rbutton"  name="radio[]" value="3"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rbutton"  name="radio[]" value="4" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Only one radio button can be selected based on your HTML. Either give them different names or make them checkboxes. The whole point of radio buttons are to only select one.

Comment: ok so suppose i use type="checkbox" instead i still need help in the Jquery part please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use checkboxes instead

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="rbutton"  name="radio[]" value="1" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="rbutton"  name="radio[]" value="2" /></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="rbutton"  name="radio[]" value="3"/></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="rbutton"  name="radio[]" value="4" /></li>
</ul>​
```

SCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    var $inputs = $('input.rbutton');
    $inputs.change(function() {
        if ($('input.rbutton:checked').length == 2) {
            $inputs.not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $inputs.prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D2QgX/

Actually heres how you can do it without the if/else statement

```
$(function() {
    var $inputs = $('input.rbutton');
    $inputs.change(function() {       
           $inputs.not(':checked').prop('disabled', $('input.rbutton:checked').length == 2);       
    });
});​
```

Comment: tx just what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sMz97/1/)**

```
var MAX = 2;
$('input.rbutton').click(function() {
    ($('input.rbutton:checked').length == MAX) ? $('input.rbutton').not(':checked').attr('disabled',true):$('input.rbutton').not(':checked').attr('disabled',false);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you change your type to `type="checkbox"` To disable a button, simply add the disabled attribute to the element. This code does the trick.

```
MAX = 2;

$('.rbutton').click(function(){
  var checked = [];
  $('.rbutton').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
      checked.push(this);
    });
  if(checked.length == MAX)
    $('.rbutton').each(function(){
      if($.inArray(this, checked) == -1)
          $(this).attr({disabled:'disabled'});
      });
});​
```

Any time a checkbox is checked, it counts all of the checked checkboxes, and if that count equals the max, it disables all of them. It also allows you to uncheck and they are re-enabled. [See it working here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mydGf/1/)

Comment: That disables all the checkboxes. OP said "when 2 are checked than disable the rest.", not disable them all.

Answer (score 0):

You will need checkboxes, not radio buttons. But this should help once you have checkboxes named "checkbox[]":

```
var $inputs = $('form input[type="checkbox"][name="checkbox\\[\\]"]');
$inputs.click(function()
{
    if ($inputs.filter('*:checked').length >= MAX)
    {   $inputs.attr('disabled','disabled'); }
    else
    {   $inputs.removeAttr('disabled');      }
});
```

Comment: I pulled it from working code of mine. I just wrapped it in an event handler. I'm sorry, I assumed you would put this code in a "click" handler.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the same name actually messes it up as you cannot select more than one radio button having the same name.. try giving different names to your radio buttons.. Or use checkboxes entirely..

```
 <li><input type="radio" class="rbutton"  name="radio[1]" value="1" /></li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rbutton"  name="radio[2]" value="2" /></li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rbutton"  name="radio[3]" value="3"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" class="rbutton"  name="radio[4]" value="4" /></li>
```